# PHPStorm - type hinting with arrays

Tags: php, arrays, phpstorm, type-hinting

You can type hint arrays like this:

```
/** @var Class[] $variable */
$variable = /*someArrayWithObjects*/;
```

But is it possible to type hint the array as itself **and** the objects of the Array differently? Something like:

```
/** @var Class, SomeOtherClass[] $variable */
$variable = /*someArrayWithObjects*/;
```

So that the array itself shows methods from `Class` and every Object of the array shows methods from `SomeOtherClass`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. You can specify that `$variable` is, for example, a `Collection` or an array of `SomeOtherClass`:

```
/** @var Collection|SomeOtherClass[] $variable */
$variable = /*someArrayWithObjects*/;
```

This will give you code completion for `Collection` on `$variable` and also for the methods in `SomeOtherClass` when you iterate over the items in `$variable`. This of course assumes that you can iterate over `$variable`.